# How to create a QTreeWidget with QTools?

Tags: common-lisp

I'd like to create a QTreeWidget with simple rows (no hierarchy), a column with an image, and other columns with textual information.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html

I'm looking at [QTools](https://github.com/Shinmera/qtools) and [Qtools-ui](https://github.com/Shinmera/qtools-ui) and, while their examples work fine, I can't find a TreeView example nor do I understand how to deal with all this Qt machinery.

I did find that the right class exists…

```
(org.shirakumo.qtools+common-lisp:find-qt-class-name "qtreewidget")
"QTreeWidget"
t
```

*edit*: a grep does find a `QTreeWidget` in the Qtools sources, but no `make-qtreewidget`.

No need to say I'm new to Qt.

Any example is welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example of a QTreeWidget:

```
(defpackage #:qtools-tree
  (:use #:cl+qt)
  (:export #:main))

(in-package #:qtools-tree)
(in-readtable :qtools)

(define-widget main-window (QWidget)
  ())

(define-subwidget (main-window tree) (q+:make-qtreewidget main-window)
  (setf (q+:column-count tree) 3)
  (mapc (lambda (item)
          (q+:add-top-level-item tree
                                 (q+:make-qtreewidgetitem tree (list item))))
        '("Sun" "Mercury" "Venus" "Earth" "Mars"))
  (q+:resize-column-to-contents tree 0))

(define-subwidget (main-window layout) (q+:make-qvboxlayout main-window)
  (q+:add-widget layout tree))

(defun main ()
  (with-main-window (window (make-instance 'main-window))))
```

Comment: With the first `define-widget` I get `#<sb-kernel::undefined-alien-function-error sw_find_class`. I'll try with a recent SBCL ±next week, I'm on the old 1.2.4 now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know what's the oldest SBCL version qtools will work with… Are you quickloading `(ql:quickload '(qtools qtcore qtgui))`? Did you try the examples on the qtools repository? Are they working on your system?

Comment: I had not quickloaded all three of them, now it works ! (and yes the examples work)